# How to change tinymce plugin icon

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using the jbimages plug-in.  I'd like to use a different icon from tinymce_icons.gif  I know where to make the change, but not what it should be.  In jbimages I found the following code:

```
// Add a button that opens a window
editor.addButton('jbimages', {
    tooltip: 'Upload an image',
    icon : 'image',
    text: 'Upload',
    onclick: jbBox
});
```

So where do I found a list of the icon names so I can change it to the icon I want?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to find the icons and choose the one you want:

TinyMCE version 4 no longer uses tinymce_icons.gif. It uses the icomoon font.

Find the icon you want in icomoon and note the character code (E034 in my case).
Find the character code in skin.min.css.
Look at the name of the css class that inserts that character code (.mce-i-browse in my case).
The icon name is what follows .mce-i ("browse" for me)
I replaced the icon name in plugin.min.js

More information: In Windows you can discover the character code as follows:
Install the font.
Start Word and go to Insert Symbol (more symbols).
Chose the icomoon font.
View the character code in the Insert Symbol dialog.

Comment: You don't have to use Word, there is Character Map application. But the tinymce font is smaller than standard icomoon icon set

Comment: What if a desired icon does not exist in tinymce font, but does exist in icomoon font. Is there any way to add?